# Direct proof methods

Tags: analysis, logic

Why is that if we want to show that $A \implies B$, we assume $A$ holds and show that $B$ also must hold? How about the other casses in the truth table, notably, when $A$ is false?

$B$ can be either true or false, but how can we show that this is the case? For example, what if we have that when $A$ does not hold, then $B$ is always false, or vice versa?

Comment: If $A$ doesn’t hold, you make no conclusion. You don’t need to *show* that $B$ can be either true or false, since that’s tautologically the case.

Comment: There is only one way for the implication to be false, and that is for A to be true and B to be false. If you can show that If A is true, B is true, then the implication holds.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is false, then $A \to B$ is true, no matter whether $B$ is true or false, and so there is no need to figure out the truth-value of $B$. Indeed, this is why we can disregard the very case where $A$ is false, and why we can just concentrate on the case where $A$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

$A\implies B$ takes two booleans $A$ and $B$ and gives back a new boolean. The interactions look like this:

$$ (F\implies F) = T \\ (T\implies F) = F \\ (F\implies T) = T \\ (T\implies T) = T$$

Now, suppose you have a couple statements $A$ and $B$ and want to prove that $A\implies B$. What you're trying to prove is that $A\implies B$ is always true, i.e. that it is never false. The only way that $A\implies B$ would be false is if $A$ were true but $B$ were false. Thus, if you can show that whenever $A$ is true, $B$ is also true, then every *actually possible* pair of choices for $A$ and $B$ will make $A\implies B$ true, *regardless* of what happens when $A$ is false.